# How to create a module object by content in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string which contains a python code. Is there a way to create a python module object using the string without an additional file?

```
content = "import math\n\ndef f(x):\n    return math.log(x)"

my_module = needed_function(content) # <- ???

print my_module.f(2) # prints 0.6931471805599453
```

Please, don't suggest using `eval` or `exec`. I need a python module object exactly. Thanks!

Comment: I just wonder why you'd *need* a real separate module for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create an empty modules with `imp` module then load your code in the module with `exec`.

```
content = "import math\n\ndef f(x):\n    return math.log(x)"

import imp
my_module = imp.new_module('my_module')
exec content in my_module.__dict__ # in python 3, use exec() function

print my_module.f(2)
```

This is my answer, but I do not recommend using this in an actual application.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Of course, you should never ever do this.

Comment: just learned about `exec .. in ..`, "nice"

Comment: how would you do it now, once `imp` module is deprecated and up for removal in 3.12?